# How to version an api endpoint in .net

Tags: c#, json, api, architecture

We're setting up a bunch of json web services in ASP.NET which is served as .ashx (custom handlers) files.  An example would be:

```
/mobile/json.ashx
```

We'd like to implement some form of versioning as well as to not break apps which has not upgraded.  So we led down this path:

```
/mobile/json.ashx?v=1.0
```

Now, of course we have have a switch statement in our custom handlers to manage the differences between api version but this doesn't sound like a very maintainable solution to me.

What are the best practises for this kind of set up and what options are available for  version control?

Thanks

Comment: Not enough details. What technologies are you using? ASP.NET MVC? Or something else?

Comment: It's an ASP.NET application.  The question is about class design and application logic and not really about the technology stack.

Answer (score 2):

Placing the version in the query parameters (that is, after the `?`) suggests to the user that each endpoint is individually versioned. I would avoid this.

If your web service is structured such that there are larger logical units that are being individually versioned, then I would go with something like this:

```
/api1/1.0/some/endpoint
/api1/1.1/some/endpoint
/api2/1.0/some/other/endpoint
/api2/2.0/some/other/endpoint
...
```

The version portion of the path comes directly after the thing which is being versioned. This suggests to the user that everything underneath `/api1/1.1/` is version 1.1 of API 1 and everything underneath `/api2/2.0/` is version 2.0 of API 2.

If someone entirely omits the version portion of the path, the latest version should be implied.  So `/api2/some/other/endpoint` would map to, say, `/api2/2.0/some/other/endpoint`.

If you're using ASP.NET MVC, all of this can be accomplished very easy using route configuration in the `RegisterRoutes` method in `Global.asax.cs`.  For example:

```
routes.MapRoute("api1/1.1", "api1/1.1/some/endpoint",
    new { controller = "Api1_1_1", action = "SomeEndpoint" });
```

where you have a controller class `Api1_1_1` with method `SomeEndpoint`.

Comment: I would respectfully suggest that using dot notation for a REST API indicates you're making breaking changes way too often.

Comment: @EricStein Hahaha yeah - the OP's choice not mine. :P